# How can I use LocalStorage in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I know this question has been asked many times in stackoverflow but none of them seems helping me with my problem. Can anyone help me with any suggestion or a answer will be help. I'm kind a stuck in this part.

## Here is my code

```
``const getItemFromLocalStorage = (key) =\> {
 let value;
 if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  value = window.localStorage.getItem(key)
  ? JSON.parse(
  window.localStorage.getItem(key)
  ): null;
 } else {
  console.log(
  "Get Item You are on the server can not use window.localStorage"
 ); }
 return value;
};

const setItemToLocalStorage = (key, value) =\> {
 if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
 } else {
  console.log(
   "Set Item You are on the server can not use window.localStorage"
  );
 }
};

const removeItemFromLocalStorage = (key) =\> {
 if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
 } else {
  console.log(
   "Remove Item You are on the server can not use window.localStorage"
  );
 }
};

const clearLocalStorage = () =\> {
 if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  window.localStorage.clear();
 } else {
  console.log(
   "Clear Item You are on the server can not use window.localStorage"
  );
 }
};`
`
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Node.js does not have a window object, It's only available in browsers, If you want to store something you can use a global variable but it's not recommended because that will be only available in current server instance and can't be shared between multiple instances. You can use persistent storage like database mongodb, redis, etc to solve such cases.

Comment: @RahulSharma I building a login system where user can login with otp I will sent the otp mail and they will use but the otp will valid for 5 minutes only i want to store in localstorage and after 5 minutes localStorage will clear. If i store it mongo db I don't know if there any way to clear a particular field so came up with localstorage is there any other way you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

### You Can't

*At least, not how you think...*

Back-end applications do not have access to front-end objects, such as `window`, and, in your case, `window.localStorage`; they're running in a completely separate environment.

You *can* emulate it using a package such as [node-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage), but if you want to store data specific to the user, that can be accessed in your back-end application, you should either do it using a database, such as [MySQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) or [Redis](https://redis.io/docs/clients/nodejs/):

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'yourDbName'
});
 
conn.connect();

conn.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', (error, results, fields) => {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
 
conn.end();
```

Or store the data *temporarily* in a [session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

If you have a case where you need to store some information on the client that is provided by the back-end, you'll need to retrieve it using an [Ajax](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) request and *then* store it.

Answer (score -1):

As you said,

> I building a login system where user can login with otp I will sent
> the otp mail and they will use but the otp will valid for 5 minutes
> only i want to store in localstorage and after 5 minutes
> localStorage will clear. If i store it mongo db I don't know if
> there any way to clear a particular field so came up with
> localstorage is there any other way you suggest.

You can do something like that,

Store otp in Database and on successful login you can delete otp from table and if user not logged in that 5 min then you have to add one field in table which you can use as expire time for otp and while checking for valid otp you can check whether otp is entered within 5 minute or not

I have done something like this.